# Numpy csv file groupby

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm reading a `CSV` file with two columns. The second column describes a label. I would like to see how many of each labels exists in my `CSV` file.

My solution involves a simple `for` loop and a `dictionary` object:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt(input_file, invalid_raise=False, missing_values='N/A', delimiter=",", dtype=str,
                            skip_header=1)
    np.load

    X = dataset[:, 0]
    y = dataset[:, 1]
    classes = dict()
    for label in y:
        if label in classes:
            classes[label] += 1
        else:
            classes[label] = 1

    print classes
```

Example:

```
{'Error Processing Payment': 1, 'General Question': 1, 'Display': 5, 'Software': 2}
```

**I was wondering if there is a `NumPy` function like `groupby`, which will give me the same functionality?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy's fancy indexing by turning your dataset into a structured array:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt(input_file, invalid_raise=False, missing_values='N/A', delimiter=",", dtype=[('data', 'S50'), ('label', 'S50')],
                        skip_header=1)
```

and then you get the frequency for `'Error Processing Payment'` as simple as:

```
len(dataset[dataset['label'] == 'Error Processing Payment'])
```

also, you get all available labels using:

```
set(dataset['label'])
```